# What do I need to setup in order to push a video stream to the web

Tags: webcam, streaming-video, camera

I'm interested in using a Raspberry Pi and some webcam to stream video to the web.

First, I would need to know how to setup the webcam.
Second I would like to know if it is possible to push a stream to some service like Ustream.

UPDATE:
Can I just plug in any modern USB webcam? Or do I need to install some driver?
Is there a Ustream client that will run on the RPi, or any other similar client that will push live stream to them web?

Comment: This question is quite vague. Have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To stream to services like UStream you can use `ffmpeg`:

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 -qscale 1 -r 25 -vcodec libx264 -b 636k -aspect 4:3 -s 640x480 -ar 44100 -ab 64k -async 1 -g 6 -threads 2 -f flv  "${RTMP_URL}/${KEY} flashver=FME/2.5\20(compatible;\20FMSc\201.0)"
```

Where:

- `/dev/video0`: where your webcam is connected on Linux
- `RTMP_URL`: Ustream channel RTMP server URL to publis
- `KEY`: Your Ustream channel KEY

(You can find RTMP_URL and KEY on Ustream Dashboard->Your channelname->Remote section)

Also, I could stream my webcam to my Wowza Media Server (over RTMP) with this:

```
ffmpeg -re -i /dev/video -qscale 1 -r 25 -vcodec libx264 -vpre fastfirstpass -b 636k -aspect 4:3 -s 640x480 -ar 44100 -ab 64k -async 1 -g 6 -f mp4 -threads 2 rtmp://192.168.1.6/live/webcam
```

Answer (score 1):

There is lots of hardware [confirmed to work with RPI](http://elinux.org/RPi_VerifiedPeripherals), so in simple terms - many or even most of USB web cameras will work with RPI.

On the streaming side of things - check out [motion](http://www.lavrsen.dk/foswiki/bin/view/Motion/WebHome). [Here is](http://pingbin.com/2012/12/raspberry-pi-web-cam-server-motion/) a good example of setup.

Answer (score 0):

I believe ustream uses flash. Also, adobe flash media encoder is out of the question since it doesn't work on any OS other than mac/windows.

Comment: Makes sense. So what other option is there to push out a video stream?

Answer (score 0):

Using VLC you can send a stream and play it within the network. I haven't tried doing this from another network but somehow there should be a way. If not directily from VLC, then via a website.

Using this code in HTML you can create a website with the stream:

```
<OBJECT classid="clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921"
            codebase="http://downloads.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/latest/win32/axvlc.cab"
            width="640" height="360" id="vlc" events="True">
            <param name="Src" value="rtsp://cameraipaddress" />
            <param name="ShowDisplay" value="True" />
            <param name="AutoLoop" value="False" />
            <param name="AutoPlay" value="True" />
            <embed id="vlcEmb"  type="application/x-google-vlc-plugin" version="VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2" autoplay="yes" loop="no" width="640" height="360"
            target="rtsp://***.***.***.***:8554/" controls="false"></embed>
</OBJECT>
```